# Combining IPTV and Internet over one Ethernet cable

Tags: ethernet, iptv

The TV/Internet in my rental apartment is provided through a modem supplied by my ISP, and this modem has one Ethernet outlet for Internet access (to which I have connected a wireless router) and one Ethernet outlet for TV. The (Gigabit) Ethernet cable used for TV is wired inside a wall as the TV set and decoder box are on the other side of the apartment.

I would like to move my wireless router to the other side of the apartment as well, and avoid having to wire another Ethernet cable through the walls in my apartment. I've found ways to do this at speeds of 10 Mbps, but that is unfortunately too slow for me. Is it in any way possible to combine IPTV and Internet in the same Ethernet cable while still getting speeds of at least 100 Mbps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can route two ethernet segments over one physical ethernet line using [VLAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_LAN).

The modem/router supplied by your ISP is very likely already receiving TV/Internet on different VLANs from your ISP, so if it's possible to configure it in such a way that it outputs both already tagged on one if its ports, then you don't need any additional hardware next to your ISP modem/router.

On the other end, you'll either need hardware capable of decoding VLANs, or additional hardware.

Comment: What will I need if it can't be configured in that way? The modem is not configurable by the user -- only remotely by the ISP. I doubt I could convince them to configure it in such a way over the phone.

Comment: If the modem is not configurable, you need a piece of hardware with at least three ethernet ports, which you can configure to tag two incoming ports with VLAN and forward it to the third port (and back). I guess basically all embedded systems running Linux where you can become root would work, there's even hardware you can buy especially for this purpose (search for "ethernet" + "switch" + "VLAN") on amazon etc.